# Not to apply server's default textures

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on a Minecraft server with a friend, and he wants to put a texture pack on the server (he is the Administrator).

However, I'd like to keep the original texture pack.

Is it possible for me not to apply the texture pack?

When I launch the game, whatever happens, the texture pack is downloaded and applied, even if I delete it beforehand. I can't stop the download.

I can't re-select the old texture pack either.

So, is there a solution?

Comment: If your friend uses the `texture-pack` server property you should get a message like: "The server recommends that you use a certain texture pack..." that you can then decline. What MC version are you using? Is it a Minecraft or a Bukkit server? If the latter, how does your friend set up the server side texture pack?

Comment: Correction: the property is called `resource-pack`

Comment: @MrLemon, you are right. I've deleted the %appdata% folder and that works. However, once I've accepted that once, I can't get back and choose not to apply that anymore. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Pre 1.7.6

1. Hit ESC to go to the Pause Menu.
2. Go to Options on the Pause Menu.
3. Click Video Settings
4. Change your Server Textures to OFF.
5. Click Done twice then disconnect.
6. Reconnect to the server.

If you want to turn the Server Texture Pack on again, go to the options menu, video settings, turn Server textures ON, click done twice, disconnect then reconnect to the server.

Screenshot for Minecraft 1.7.2
[image]

#### Post 1.7.6

The server resource packs option is now per-server, and has three settings: prompt, enabled, and disabled. It can be set in the Server settings.

Comment: According to the [Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Options#Video_Settings), the Option is under Server Settings rather than Video Settings, but I can't check right now.

Comment: @MrLemon sorry it is under video settings - there is no server settings option but there is multiplayer option i have edited my post with a photo of the video settings menu.

Comment: What version are you using @Flaunting? You are definitely not using the latest version. I can confirm there is a Server Settings sub-menu in the latest version on Minecraft (1.7.10) which contains the Server Textures option.

Comment: this is with 1.7.2 as i have optifine installed for 1.7.10 so couldn't get a proper screenshot

Comment: @Caleb phew, for a moment there I feared the almighty wiki was actually wrong... Thanks for restoring my faith.

Comment: @MrLemon Have edited the post to incorporate this so it covers all versions. as we still don't know what versions they were using

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found out what to do for every case in the last version of Minecraft. So here it is :

When you create a server, you can "EDIT" the options of the server. In there, is a command box which asks the question if we want to use the server's texture pack or not.

Just choose the right answer between "Enable", "Disable", or "Prompt".

Comment: Why have you answered your own question? I think you should accept [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/176918/96630) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. For some reason, It's not there. So what you do is go into your .minecraft folder and delete a folder "server-resource-packs".  When you join the sever, there  should be a thing telling you that it's downloading the resource pack.  Hit ESC and it will cancel the download.

Hope this helped!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still needing to know how with later versions and haven't found out how to disable them, select the server from your list of servers after hitting Multiplayer, click edit. Just below the IP is the option to disable resource packs.